# ¿Como puedo usar ANSI.sys en programas de c?

Tags: c

Estoy creando un programa en c y la salida del programa muestra un hello World por consola pero le quiero dar colores en formato ANSI el código es el siguiente

```
#include <stdio>
#include <stdlib>

int main(void){
    const char *const verde = "\033[0;40;32m";
    const char *const subrayado_fazul_verde = "\033[4;44;32m";
    const char *const normal = "\033[0m";

    printf("Mostrando %scolores%s !!!\n", verde, normal);
    printf("Mostrando %scolores%s !!!\n", subrayado_fazul_verde, normal);

    return 0;
}
```

La cuestión es que el programa me funciona perfectamente en Linux, pero cuando copilo el programa para Windows el texto no sale en colores, investigue y consegui que se puede usar ANSI.sys el cual sirve para dar formato al texto por consola, quisiera saber cómo usarla en programas en c, o si abría otra forma de dar colores al texto en Windows (no quiero hacer uso de conio.h ya que no viene instalada por defecto)

Answer (score 2):

En la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes) de Windows encontrarás que debes usar la función [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute) para ese propósito con los posibles valores. O si prefieres puedes consultar la [lista de funciones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) relacionadas a la consola.

El primer parámetro es un HANDLE del buffer de salida y lo puedes obtener con la función [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle).

```
HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```

El segundo parámetro es una máscara de bits de los atributos a establecer.

Para el color del texto hay 4 atributos **FOREGROUND_RED**, **FOREGROUND_GREEN**, **FOREGROUND_BLUE** y **FOREGROUND_INTENSITY**. Cada uno correspondiente al rojo, verde y azul respectivamente.

Por defecto los colores son oscuros así que el atributo **FOREGROUND_INTENSITY** sirve para hacerlo más claro o *intenso* como indica su nombre.

Naturalmente te preguntarás, ¿Cómo obtener otros colores si solo hay 4?

La respuesta es simple, combinando los 4 atributos.

Saber cuál combinación usar es simple. Busca una tabla de colores RGB que te enseña qué colores obtienes a partir de una combinación, como esta:

[image: Colores RGB]

Supón que quieres el color cian. Bueno, según la tabla necesitas azul y verde. Para obtenerlo, la instrucción es la siguiente:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
```

Y si quieres hacerlo más claro:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
```

Probablemente encuentres útil crear algunas constantes o macros con cada combinación posible para hacer el código más simple.

Para el fondo existen 4 atributos, **BACKGROUND_RED**, **BACKGROUND_GREEN**, **BACKGROUND_BLUE** y **BACKGROUND_INTENSITY** que funcionan de la misma manera.

---

### Importante

> If no background constant is specified, the background is black, and if no foreground constant is specified, the text is black. Red, green, and blue are specified for the background which combines to a white background. No flag colors are specified for the foreground so it is black.

Si no se especifica ningún atributo para el fondo, se establece en negro. Lo mismo sucede con el texto. Si no se especifica ningún atributo para el color del texto, se establece en negro.

Puedes acceder a las funciones mencionadas a través de la cabecera **Windows.h**. (`#include <Windows.h>`)

No olvides leer [la documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes) para que te quede más claro y no perderte información que no se haya mencionado en esta respuesta.